# Inverse tabulate function in MATLAB

Tags: performance, matlab

I have an array `freq` with frequencies and another one `val` with values.

```
val =[1 3 5 7];    
freq=[2 3 3 2];
```

I want to get the array `result`.

```
result=[1 1 3 3 3 5 5 5 7 7];
```

One of the methods I've tried to get `result` is:

```
freq=[2 3 3 2];
val=[1 3 5 7];
result=[];
for i=1:length(val);
    result=[result repmat(val(i),1,freq(i))];
end
```

It works, but with large arrays I expect some performance gain if I get rid of the `for`-loop. Is there any built in function for this? How would you calculate `result` for large arrays?

Comment: Minor improvement to the loop can be achieved by preallocating `result` to `result = zeros(1, sum(freq))`, and handling indexing appropriately in the loop.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This can be made that way:

```
val = [1 3 5 7]
freq = [2 3 3 2]
res = repelem(val, freq)

res =

 1     1     3     3     3     5     5     5     7     7
```

Answer (score 2):

For large vectors, you could gain some performance by preallocating `result` and updating multiple cells at the same time.

```
result = zeros(sum(freq), 1);
j = 1;
for i=1:length(freq);
    result(j:j+freq(i)-1) = val(i);
    j = j + freq(i);
end;
```